# Remove Integration connection Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I was trying to remove an Integration from Magento 2.2.7
in

> System => Extension => Integration

but unfortunately the delete icon (trash) is not clickable and i can't proceed
to remove the connection.

[image]

Comment: You can delete from a database.

Comment: what is the relative table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Database 
Search integration table 
go to Setup_type field
check value
if value is 1 set to 0 
remove cache
refresh backend
now your delete button(icon) will be enable.

try out

Answer (score 0):

in the database, update the value of `setup_type` field into 1 in `integration` table

refresh the Integration page and the delete icon should be enabled and clickable